# Merging two datasets by column name 'Name'

Tags: merge, dataset

I am trying to merge two datasets for a project and am curious as to how I merge the two under the similar column 'Name'. I tried and so far the output doesn't print out any data along with it.

```
import pandas as pd

#importing the two datasets
Data1 = pd.read_csv('Desktop/MLB.csv')
Data2 = pd.read_csv('Downloads/Untitled spreadsheet - Sheet1.csv')

#making a name column to merge the two with
Data1['Name'] = (Data1['Last Name'] + ' ' + ',' + ' ' + '-' + Data1['First Name'].astype(str).str[0] + '-')
Data2['Name'] = Data2['Player']

#isolating the desired columns
Data3 = Data2.loc[:,['Pos', '-G-', '-AB-', '-R-', '-H-', '2B', '3B', '-HR-','RBI', 'BB', '-SO-', '-SB-', '-CS-', 'AVG▼', 'OBP', '-SLG-', 'OPS', 'Name']]
Data4 = Data1.loc[:,['Position', 'FPPG', 'Name']]

#merging the two datasets
Data5 = pd.merge(Data3, Data4, on='Name')
Data5

#the output
Pos -G- -AB-    -R- -H- 2B  3B  -HR-    RBI BB  -SO-    -SB-    -CS- AVG▼ OBP   -SLG-   OPS Name    Position    FPPG
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Best,
Brendan.